# Event triggered when Craft sends email

Tags: plugin-development, events

Is there an event that would be triggered every time email is being sent by Craft? So email message can be intercepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `craft\mail\Mailer::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND`.

You can use the [Event Code Generator](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/events.html#event-code-generator) to find out more